# How to encrypt file or blocking access to file and only execute apache?

Tags: permissions, apache2, filesystem, files, encryption

My operating system is ubuntu server 14.04. I want to encrypt /var/www folder. I've tried for blocking access to file with `chown -R www-data /var/www` and `chmod 700` commands. Any unix user can not open this folder without root . But I can open this file with any windows operating system. I want to encrypt or blocking access to everywhere and any operating system can not access this file.

Comment: What sense makes it to encrypt a directory which will get published by apache?

Answer (score 0):

A caveat: I have never done this myself, but I was contemplating it... hence I looked it up. You create an encrypted folder with encfs, see [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption).

Basically, you back-up and move your `/var/www` directory to a temporary location. Than you recreate it as described in the help page, copy in your old contents (`cp -R <from> <to>`) and `chown` it properly.

If needed, the help page provides some hooks for how to start the decryption automatically, if you would like that.

Good luck with it!

Jeroen